# how to plot horizontal errorbar in matlab R2010a ?

Tags: matlab, plot, draw

Please any one help, I can't plot a horizontal `errorbar` in matlab.

Example:

```
figure(1)
errorbar(C(:,2),C(:,3),C(:,5),'.b')
title('error bar for dx')
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
```

Comment: Did you try to Google it up? For example, see [this link](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-172TG/?product=ML&solution=1-172TG)...

Answer (score 3):

There's a function [`herrorbar`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3963) available from the MATLAB Central File Exchange that will do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's helpful to define the used variables.

```
X=mean(xall)
Y=mean(yall)
```

whereas `xall` and `yall` are all experimental data.

```
err1=std(yall)
err2=std(xall)
```

these are the variables, after that i wrote

```
errorbar(x,y,err1....)
herrorbar(x,Y,err2...)
```

Matlab writes

> undefined function 'herrorbar'for input arguments of type 'double'.
>   Error...
>   herrorbar(X,Y,err2,'r');